# Python: My python plot is reflecting across y = 0.5 line

Tags: python, matplotlib, wolfram-mathematica

Why would my Python plot reflect across the `y = 0.5` line?  The same plot in Mathematica doesn't.  I checked the equations 5-10 times and I don't see a difference.  If I put a `-1` in front of the python plot it will flip over and drop down 1 unit to `y = -0.5`.

Additionally, the definitions for `alphag` and `betag` are correct.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab

r1 = 1  #  AU Earth                                                                 
r2 = 1.524  #  AU Mars                                                              
deltanu = 75 * np.pi / 180  #  angle in radians                                     
mu = 38.86984154054163                                        

c = np.sqrt(r1 ** 2 + r2 ** 2 - 2 * r1 * r2 * np.cos(deltanu))

s = (r1 + r2 + c) / 2

am = s / 2


def g(a):
    alphag = 2* np.pi - 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(s / (2 * a)))
    betag = -2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt((s - c) / (2 * a)))
    return (np.sqrt(a ** 3 / mu)
            * (alphag - betag - (np.sin(alphag) - np.sin(betag)))
            - dt)


a = np.linspace(am, 2, 500000)
dt = np.linspace(0, 2, 500000)

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(a, g(a), color = 'r')
pylab.xlim((0.9, 2))
pylab.ylim((0, 2))

pylab.show()
```

Python:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

There are actually 2 plots I am plotting and thanks to the comments, I noticed that there is something even stranger occurring.

The two plots I am plotting are:

```
dt = np.sqrt(a ** 3 / mu) * (alpha - beta - (sin(alpha) - sin(beta)))
```

where `alpha` is `2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(s / (2 * a)))` or `2 * np.pi - 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(s / (2 * a)))` and `beta` is `2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt((s - c) / (2 * a)))` or the negative of the first.

```
In[13]:= r1 = 1;
r2 = 1.524;
dnu = 75 Degree;
mu = 38.86984154054163;

In[17]:= c = Sqrt[r1^2 + r2^2 - 2*r1*r2*Cos[dnu]]

Out[17]= 1.59176

In[18]:= s = (r1 + r2 + c)/2

Out[18]= 2.05788

In[19]:= alp = 2 \[Pi] - 2*ArcSin[Sqrt[s/(2*a)]];
bet = -2*ArcSin[Sqrt[(s - c)/(2*a)]];

In[22]:= Plot[
 Sqrt[a^3/mu]*(alp - bet - (Sin[alp] - Sin[bet])), {a, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{.8, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

This produces:

[image]

and

```
alp2 = 2*ArcSin[Sqrt[s/(2*a)]];
bet2 = 2*ArcSin[Sqrt[(s - c)/(2*a)]];

Plot[Sqrt[a^3/mu]*(alp2 - bet2 - (Sin[alp2] - Sin[bet2])), {a, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{.8, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]

So the Python code matches the first Mathematica code but the plots the second picture and my python code for the the second Mathematica codes produces the flipped image for the first Mathematica picture.

Comment: Where is the equivalent of `dt` in the Mathematica plot?

Comment: @unutbu in Mathematica, that is just y.  We don't have to set it equal to zero by subtracting `dt` as we do in Python.

Comment: Please post the full Mathematica code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with matplotlib, but does it somehow iterate over the dt that's buried in the function?

Comment: @george unutbu found the problem.  It was don't use dt but I have always had to set the equations I have plotted equal to 0; that is, subtracting over the left hand side.  I asked if he/she knew why that wasn't the case here.  If you happen to know, don't hesitate to let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply have to remove the `-dt` from the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r1 = 1  #  AU Earth                                                                 
r2 = 1.524  #  AU Mars                                                              
deltanu = 75 * np.pi / 180  #  angle in radians                                     
mu = 38.86984154054163                                        

c = np.sqrt(r1 ** 2 + r2 ** 2 - 2 * r1 * r2 * np.cos(deltanu))

s = (r1 + r2 + c) / 2

am = s / 2


def g(a):
    alphag = 2 * np.pi - 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(s / (2 * a)))
    betag = -2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt((s - c) / (2 * a)))
    return (np.sqrt(a ** 3 / mu)
            * (alphag - betag - (np.sin(alphag) - np.sin(betag))))

def g2(a):
    alphag = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(s / (2 * a)))
    betag = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt((s - c) / (2 * a)))
    return (np.sqrt(a ** 3 / mu)
            * (alphag - betag - (np.sin(alphag) - np.sin(betag))))


a = np.linspace(am, 2, 500000)
dt = np.linspace(0, 2, 500000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax[0].plot(a, g(a), color = 'r')
ax[1].plot(a, g2(a), color = 'r')
ax[0].set_xlim((0.9, 2))
ax[0].set_ylim((0, 2))
ax[1].set_xlim((0.9, 2))
ax[1].set_ylim((0, 2))

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned that in mathematica they are defined with a negative and in python I used the odd functionality of sine to move them out.

Comment: I always thought with Python that I needed to set the plotted equations to 0 so subtracting over the LHS?  With my other plots, this worked.  Do you know why this wasn't the case in this instance?

Comment: Banish that thought. Matplotlib's `plot` function simply plots the data given to it. Of course, it depends on what function you are using, `plt.contour(x, y, f, [0])` does plot the level curve where `f=0`...